# Editing an Access Database using Multiple Identical Methods via C#/OledB

Tags: c#, oledb, ms-access-2010

I am trying to update data/a record on an Access 2010 Database through C# using an OledB connection and trying to make an application that is able to insert and update data into the database.

My application consists of 3 forms that can insert & update the data into a record, so far i have got one of these working but struggling to do the other two

The error i am receiving is: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties.

In my opinion i think the error is due to having mand multiple update methods that all use data from different forms and this is causing the error but i am not sure how to correc this so i am asking for some help.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClassLibrary;
using System.Data;

namespace ClassLibrary2
    {
    public class Class1
    {
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbCommand command;

        private void ConnectTo()
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\CMS\CustomerDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
        }
        public Class1()
        {
            ConnectTo();
        }

        public void Insert(Customer p)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CustomerData ([Forename], [Surname], [Email Address], [Home Phone Number], [Mobile Phone Number], [Address], [AreaTown], [County], [Postcode]) VALUES('" + p.Forename1 + "', '" + p.Surname1 + "', '" + p.EAddress1 + "', '" + p.HomePhone1 + "' , '" + p.MobNum1 + "' , '" + p.Address1 + "', '" + p.AreaTown1 + "', '" + p.County1 + "', '" + p.Postcode1 + "')";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Customer> FillComboBox()
        {
            List<Customer> CustomersList = new List<Customer>();
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CustomerData";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Customer p = new Customer();

                    p.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString());
                    p.Forename1 = reader["Forename"].ToString();
                    p.Surname1 = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                    p.EAddress1 = reader["Email Address"].ToString();
                    p.HomePhone1 = reader["Home Phone Number"].ToString();
                    p.MobNum1 = reader["Mobile Phone Number"].ToString();
                    p.Address1 = reader["Address"].ToString();
                    p.AreaTown1 = reader["AreaTown"].ToString();
                    p.County1 = reader["County"].ToString();
                    p.Postcode1 = reader["Postcode"].ToString();

                    CustomersList.Add(p);
                }
                return CustomersList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomerData SET [Forename] = @newCustomer.Forename1, [Surname] = @newCustomer.Surname, [Email Address] = @newCustomer.EAddress1, [Home Phone Number]= @newCustomer.HomePhone1, [Mobile Phone Number] = @newCustomer.MobNum1, [Address]= @newCustomer.Address1, [AreaTown] = @newCustomer.AreaTown1, [County]= @newCustomer.County1, [Postcode]= @newCustomer.Postcode1 WHERE [ID] = @oldCustomer.Id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", newCustomer.Forename1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", newCustomer.Surname1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email Address", newCustomer.EAddress1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home Phone Number", newCustomer.HomePhone1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile Phone Number", newCustomer.MobNum1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", newCustomer.Address1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaTown", newCustomer.AreaTown1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", newCustomer.County1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", newCustomer.Postcode1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", oldCustomer.Id);

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomerData SET [Work to be Completed]= @newCustomer.WorkTBC1, [Work Completed]= @newCustomer.WorkComp1 WHERE [ID] = @oldCustomer.Id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Work to be Completed", newCustomer.WorkTBC1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Completed Work", newCustomer.WorkComp1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", oldCustomer.Id);

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomerData SET [Money Received]= @newCustomer.MReceived1, [Money Spent]= @newCustomer.MSpent1, [Bank Number]= @newCustomer.BankNo1, [Sort Code]= @newCustomer.SortCode1, [Account Number]= @newCustomer.AccountNo1, [Commencement Date]= @newCustomer.ComDate1, [Completion Date]= @newCustomer.CompDate1 WHERE [ID] = @oldCustomer.Id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Money Received", newCustomer.MReceived1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Money Spent", newCustomer.MSpent1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Bank Number", newCustomer.BankNo1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sort Code", newCustomer.SortCode1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account Number", newCustomer.AccountNo1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Commencement Date", newCustomer.ComDate1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Completion Date", newCustomer.CompDate1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", oldCustomer.Id);

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
             finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Delete(Customer p)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM CustomerData WHERE [ID] = " + p.Id + "";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if the code is a bit long

I've only just started using C# so may need a bit more explaining

Don't mind giving any further details or code from the forms so feel free to ask

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods of the name Update with the same signature. Rename one of them.
That is, change

```
public void Update(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer)
```

function name of one of the functions to

```
public void Update1(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer)
```

Better practice is always giving functions meaningful function names like

1. InsertCustomer (AddCustomer)
2. UpdateCustomer
3. UpdateCustomerWorkDetails
4. DeleteCustomer